# Formula to compare data in same row for exact match and return a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Basically what I'm trying to do is look for data in a row that matches exactly and have the formula give it a value.  For instance if the data is repeated more than once then, the formula gives a value of 1 i.e.

if cell:

```
             C            D           E            F            G
    5   7895-5874-17 7474-5555-1 1452-9856-17 1452-9856-17 1452-9856-17
```

The total count for the **row** is 2 (repeats twice)

Each repeated instance has a value of 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the following formula:

```
=COUNTA(C5:G5)-SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C5:G5,C5:G5))
```

The COUNTA: gives a count of all the cells that have text in them.  If all 5 are always filled then it can be replaced by the number `5`.

The SUMPRODUCT gets a count of unique cells.

Thus the difference is the number of duplicates.

[image]

---

If there are blanks in the series you will need to use following Array formula:

```
=COUNTA(C5:G5)-SUM(IF(C5:G5<>"",1/COUNTIFS(C5:G5,C5:G5,C5:G5,"<>")))
```

being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  It worked, however, it wont work when the cells are merged.  Is there a solution for this?  I didn't mention that I have cells C5 and D5 merged, thus it just C5.  It doesn't seem to like that.  When I unmerged the cells it worked.  But I really need to keep the cells merged.  Any help? thank you again

Comment: This is why merged cells are a bad idea except on output only sheets.  That formula would be much more complicated or impossible with formulas.  It would be easier with vba, but even then it would be difficult.  Sorry no easy one formula answer for that.

Comment: No problem.  Thank you so much for the help.  I'm going to unmerge the cells.  Does the same problem exists with spaces?  Meaning do the cells have to be next to each other for it to work like in your example above.  It seems like that if I have data on cell C5, skip D5 and on E5 it won work.

Comment: @j.vaz see edit.  it may even work with merged cells.

Comment: Super, it works with merged cells as well.  But for some reason it's counting everything and not just the number of duplicates as your example shows above, For the example above it's giving me 4 instead of two

Comment: Then your data is not as uniform as you think, I cannot guess as to the reason.  Look to your data and ensure that they do not have non printable things like spaces.

Comment: Scott.  Thank you so much.  I will look at the data.  You have helped me tremendously.  I solved two huge problems with this one formula  Thanks again.  This is what you helped me solved.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is determine whether there's data in any of 20 cells and give it a value of 1 if there's data.  In this case 11 digit record numbers i.e. 1245-5689-17, for a total of 20 possible points.  

However, I can't count duplicates.  So if there are any duplicate numbers I want to subtract that duplicate by 1 point.  So if there are a total of 10 cells with numbers in them and 2 are the exact same number, I would have a total of 9 points. And so on.  Thank you

Comment: Then just use the latter part it will only count unique.  But again look at your data as they would need to be exact matches.

Comment: @j.vaz please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.